# Javascript - While loop becomes infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop

For some reason, the below code causes an infinite loop. Why is that the case?

```
var attributes = responseSC.attrs;
var pos = 0;
//Find The position
while (attributes[pos].name != 'selectLocation' && pos < attributes.length) {
    pos++;
}
```

Comment: Because the conditions are never satisfied...

Comment: @DasBeasto That would be a different error, not an infinite loop. If `attributes` is an empty array, `attributs[0].name` is an exception.

Comment: Instead of while, you can have for loop to loop through your array and then compare the name inside to identify position.

Comment: @David does attributes is ever an empty array?

Comment: After analyzing your code, I cannot see any reason for a infinite loop. How have you noticed that it is actually looped?

Comment: @sam100rav no, its not empty. also, it won't go in the loop if it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

How did you conclude that it is an infinite loop? Does your page 'hang' or you get a 'Chrome ran out of memory' kind of error?

Is it simply a case of the loop never being entered and not that of forever looping ?

Answer (score 0):

The conditions are never satisfied.

why not try ES6 `findIndex`?

```
attributes.findIndex(function(element) {
  return element.name !== 'selectLocation';
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex